# SailsJs websocket with a custom route instead of blueprint?

Tags: javascript, sockets, sails.js

I am following the official Sails [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client). Would like to implement the most basic socket functionality, i.e. client connects to a socket and when server notifies it about a response, executes a script.

The problem is that the socket requests are http and I am getting badRequest.

What's the right way to register a socket route in Sails?

My client code:

```
io.socket.on('hello', function (data) {
    console.log('Socket `' + data.id + '` joined the party!')
  })
io.socket.get('/sayhello', function gotResponse(data, jwRes) {
    console.log('Server responded with status code ' + jwRes.statusCode + ' and data: ', data);
  });
```

The controller:

```
module.exports = {
exits: {
    badRequest: {
      responseType: 'badRequest',
      description: 'The provided data is invalid.',
    },
},
fn: async function (req, res) {
  if (!req.isSocket) {
    return res.badRequest();
  }
  sails.sockets.join(req, 'funSockets');
  sails.sockets.broadcast('funSockets', 'hello', {howdy: 'hi there!'}, req);
  return res.json({
    anyData: 'we want to send back'
  });
}
```

}

The route:

```
'GET /sayhello':   { action: 'project/api/app-socket' },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.js file you have:

```
'GET /sayhello':   { action: 'project/api/app-socket' },
```

Add to this `isSocket: true`. So make it:

```
'GET /sayhello':   { action: 'project/api/app-socket', isSocket: true },
```

How I learned this?

The convention for subscribe endpoints is to use an action prefixed with "subscribe", so when I generated an action with this command and this prefix:

```
sails generate action task/subscribe-to-task
```

Then it gave me this hint in the terminal output:

```
Successfully generated:
 •- api/controllers/task/subscribe-to-task.js

A few reminders:
 (1)  For most projects, you'll need to manually configure an explicit route
      in your `config/routes.js` file; e.g.
          'GET /api/v1/task/subscribe-to-task': { action: 'task/subscribe-to-task', isSocket: true },
```

That's how I learned that we needed to add `isSocket: true`.